# I am not able to access firebase real-time DB after making them secure

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have **authenticated firebase** by email/password and make database secure by changing rules but I am not able to access database.

How to **set the rule** to access database only for authentic user?

Database structure is like this:

[image: Database structure is like this]

Current set rule for database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use authStateListener to check if user is authenticated [Auth State Listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)

Comment: what is the difference between $user_id and auth.id?

Comment: grants read and  write access to the owner of this user account
  whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id).. It's a security measure such that the child that gets created for each user has same value as the auth.id of the person which you can get via ```FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
Toast.makeText(this, "" + currentFirebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();```